# Memory Allocation issue when modifying CreateToolbarEx function with new bitmap

Tags: c++, bitmap, memory-management, toolbar

I'm trying to modify some old code (c++) that uses the CreateToolbarEx function, in an attempt to use a new bitmap and replace our 24x24 pixel toolbar buttons with flashier 36x36 ones.  The function I'm using is as follows:

```
m_hToolbarWnd = CreateToolbarEx(m_hPagerWnd, ws, ID_TOOLBAR, NUMBERTOOLBARBITMAPS, hInst, IDB_TOOLBAR, tbInitButtons, m_ncButtons, 24, 24, 24, 24, sizeof(TBBUTTON));
```

I'm able to expand the size of the current toolbar buttons by changing the '24's to '36', but if I change IDB_TOOLBAR to the new toolbar bitmap and run the program I hit a memory access read violation pointing to the CreateToolbarEx function.  Am I missing something on how the bitmap is getting its memory allocation or creating the individual buttons?  The new toolbar is 1584x36 pixels (44 buttons).

Comment: The code you have above is passing 24x24 for the button and 24x24 for the bitmap still ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787469%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Correct, I just copied the working code that is in the program.  When I try to run the code with the new bitmap I change it to 36x36 for both and re-define IDB_TOOLBAR as the new bitmap.  This re-definition causes the program to crash.

Comment: You can probably import the bitmap into your application in order to create a new id IDB_TOOLBARX or whatnot.  Sometimes the resource file gets cranky if you reuse previous ids for controls or resources.

Comment: Unfortunately I had tried that before -- just attempted it again with no luck.  Any other ideas?

Comment: You could make a call to `GetLastError` after `CreateToolbarEx` to see if anything is failing outright but without seeing more code or a copy of the project I can't really tell what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is old, but hopefully the solution I found will help someone.  I had overlooked the fact that I was changing from a 16-bit color bitmap to 24-bit, which I was unable to get CreateToolbarEx to handle.  Instead, I had to call CreateWindowEx and create and set the icon ImageList for it.  Working code:

```
m_hToolbarWnd = CreateWindowEx(0L, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, "", ws, 36, 36, 36, 36, m_hPagerWnd, (HMENU) ID_TOOLBAR, hInst, NULL);
SendMessage(m_hToolbarWnd, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);
HBITMAP hBmp = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_TOOLBAR));
HIMAGELIST hIcons = ImageList_Create(36, 36, ILC_COLOR24, 0, m_ncButtons);
ImageList_Add(hIcons, hBmp, NULL);
SendMessage(m_hToolbarWnd, TB_SETIMAGELIST, 0, (LPARAM) hIcons);
```